# is there a way to add socket.io to Wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, flutter, socket.io

I'm working on a Wordpress plugin and i'm implementing APIs for a flutter mobile app and i need to add a real time listener on mysql DB. so i there a way to add Socket.io functionality to Wordpress ?